# C# Add a String to the Registry

Tags: c#, registry

I've been searching for a while now but haven't found anything.

It works, but not entirely. It finds the folders in the Registry but It won't create a String. I don't get any error about permissions or something like that. I'm running this as an Administrator.

```
            try
        {
            RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
            registryKey.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\OEMInformation", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryOptions.None);

            registryKey.SetValue("Test1","Test2");
            registryKey.Close();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? Or am I missing something important?

Thanks
DaNeubi

Comment: Seems like you are trying to set `Test1` on the root of `LocalMachine` -- you need to capture the result of `CreateSubKey` and then do `SetValue` on that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @stephen.vakil I was able to fix it.

Here's my Code now:

```
       public static Boolean WriteToRegistry(String[] OEMInformations)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < OEMInformations.Length; i = i +2)
            {
                RegistryKey mainKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
                RegistryKey firstKey = mainKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", true);
                RegistryKey secondKey = firstKey.OpenSubKey("Microsoft", true);
                RegistryKey thirdKey = secondKey.OpenSubKey("Windows", true);
                RegistryKey fourthKey = thirdKey.OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion", true);
                RegistryKey fifthKey = fourthKey.OpenSubKey("OEMInformation", true);

                fifthKey.SetValue(OEMInformations[i],OEMInformations[i + 1], RegistryValueKind.String);

                fifthKey.Close();
                fourthKey.Close();
                thirdKey.Close();
                secondKey.Close();
                firstKey.Close();
                mainKey.Close();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```